# Countable product of closed set is closed?

Tags: general-topology

This is my problem:

[image]

Let $X=\prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i$. Product of $C_i$ closed requires its complement open. i.e. $X\setminus\prod_{i=1}^\infty C_i=\prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i\setminus C_i$ open. But although $X_i\setminus C_i$ are open, product of open set may not be open. What's wrong with my steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong is the step where you say $X\setminus\prod_{i=1}^\infty C_i=\prod_{i=1}^\infty(X_i\setminus C_i)$. Not so.

For example, suppose $X_i=\{0,1\}$ and $C_i=\{0\}$. What is $X\setminus\prod_{i=1}^\infty C_i$ and what is $\prod_{i=1}^\infty(X_i\setminus C_i)$?

**Hint:** $\prod_{i=1}^\infty C_i=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty\pi_i^{-1}(C_i)$.

Use the facts that the projection maps are continuous, and continuous counterimages of closed sets are closed, and intersections of closed sets are closed.

By the way, "countable" has nothing to do with it; an arbitrary product of closed sets is closed.